# Error when I press the button

Tags: magento2, custom-button

- Create module
- Create admin grid
- Create button "ADD"
- Create Form | Controller | Block

**When I press on button "ADD"**

> Magento Admin **404 Error Page not found**

Where can there be a mistake? where to look

Comment: Check log files for more details and post if you have any doubts?

Comment: @Ranganathan 
Hello, the logs are empty. Doubts ... Hm ... I know that the request does not reach Form

Comment: Your link is misspelled or is missing the form key

Comment: @vitoriodachef form key have

From a different grid, the URL code looks like this:  **/news/post/new/key/8f9580f0148a2f05434ce5deff944e162513c931d7c049ea8a45611191a69/**
On this grid, the URL looks like this: 

**news/main/new/key/2ddcfd364fd3f0343212ed923f25c9ad6f88f20c6b7c568db5d0cea8264612d/**
but 1st grid work, second - dont work :[